# Div won't drag correctly after being scaled

Tags: javascript, html, css

If anyone could help me figure out how to make scaled draggable elements, I'd really appreciate any guidance.

Drag works fine when `transform: scale(1)`, but doesn't work correctly when something like `transform: scale(1.1)`.

I tried dividing `left` and `top` by the `scaler` while dragging but didn't work.

```js
const el = document.querySelector(".item");

let isResizing = false;

el.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);

function mousedown(e) {
  window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
  window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

  let prevX = e.clientX;
  let prevY = e.clientY;

  function mousemove(e) {
    if (!isResizing) {
      let newX = prevX - e.clientX;
      let newY = prevY - e.clientY;

      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

      el.style.left = rect.left - newX + "px";
      el.style.top = rect.top - newY + "px";

      prevX = e.clientX;
      prevY = e.clientY;
    }
  }

  function mouseup() {
    window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
  }
}

const resizers = document.querySelectorAll(".resizer");
let currentResizer;

for (let resizer of resizers) {
  resizer.addEventListener("mousedown", mousedown);

  function mousedown(e) {
    currentResizer = e.target;
    isResizing = true;

    let prevX = e.clientX;
    let prevY = e.clientY;

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
    window.addEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);

    function mousemove(e) {
      const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

      if (currentResizer.classList.contains("se")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("sw")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("ne")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
      } else {
        el.style.width = rect.width + (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height + (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
      }

      prevX = e.clientX;
      prevY = e.clientY;
    }

    function mouseup() {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", mousemove);
      window.removeEventListener("mouseup", mouseup);
      isResizing = false;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.item {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  background: pink;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.resizer {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  z-index: 2;
}

.resizer.nw {
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.resizer.ne {
  top: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  cursor: nw-resize;
}

.resizer.sw {
  bottom: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  cursor: sw-resize;
}

.resizer.se {
  bottom: -1px;
  right: -1px;
  cursor: se-resize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
  <title>Scaled Div</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="resizer ne"></div>
    <div class="resizer nw"></div>
    <div class="resizer sw"></div>
    <div class="resizer se"></div>
  </div>
  <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please include your code in the question, create a snippet - it's much easier for people to see than going off the site to another site and ensures the question is always relevant, as you fiddle link may disappear for some reason.

Comment: transform-origin reset might help for moving, resizing will go nuts because of scale anyhow . https://jsfiddle.net/uxv2nfky/

Comment: The values from `.getBoundingClientRect()` are post-`scale()` while the value from `.style` are pre-`scale()`. Also, you should get the initial value once, at the beginning, and then use dead-reckoning to figure out the new values rather than using values that are relative from frame to frame. This would help prevent drift.

Answer (score 0):

*Problem seems to be the mouse-down, conflicting between the x/y-values of the surrounding .item-div and the 4 Resize-Handlers, so the browser doesn't know which are the right resulting values ...*
So a solution of this problem may be:

1. add a CSS border to the .item {...; **border:1px solid grey** ;}

   ```
    .item {position:absolute; height:50px; width:50px; border:1px solid grey; background:pink}
   ```
2. and substract these (both-side) borders on the 4 resize-handlers:

   ```
    ...  
    el.style.width = rect.width +2+ (prevX - e.clientX) + "px"; //adding 2px  
    el.style.height = rect.height -2- (prevY - e.clientY) + "px"; //substr. 2px  
    ... etc.  
    ...
   ```

or instead of these 4 div-handlers using the default browser css-handlers:

```
    .item { ...; resize:both; overflow:hidden}
```

Answer (score 0):

...My error: "adding" 2px nevertheless should *always* substract 2px on all sides, so a mouse-down is not conflicting betw. surrounding div and handler-divs:

```
    function mousemove(e) {
    const rect = el.getBoundingClientRect(); //"rect" has no border, so add 2px for each side
    if (currentResizer.classList.contains("se")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width -2- (prevX - e.clientX) + "px"; //2 = border-width
        el.style.height = rect.height -2- (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
    
    } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("sw")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width -2+ (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height -2- (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
    
    } else if (currentResizer.classList.contains("ne")) {
        el.style.width = rect.width -2- (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height -2+ (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
    
    } else { //nw
        el.style.width = rect.width -2+ (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
        el.style.height = rect.height -2+ (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.top = rect.top - (prevY - e.clientY) + "px";
        el.style.left = rect.left - (prevX - e.clientX) + "px";
    }
```